# invite Created event

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I'm making a Discord Bot, with auto logging capabilities, until now I managed due to do most of the code, these include the command for setting a mod-log channel and the event code, here's the code for the command:

```js
let db = require(`quick.db`)

module.exports = {
  name: "modlog",
  aliases: ["modlogs", "log", "logs"],
  description: "Change the modlogs channel of the current server",
  permission: "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
  usage: "modlog #[channel_name]",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission(`MANAGE_CHANNELS`)) {
      return message.channel.send(`:x: You do not have permission to use this command!`)
    } else {
      let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
      if(!channel) return message.channel.send(`:x: Please specify a channel to make it as the modlogs!`)
      await db.set(`modlog_${message.guild.id}`, channel)
      message.channel.send(`Set **${channel}** as the server's modlog channel!`)
    }
  }
}
```

And the `inviteCreate` event:

```
client.on("inviteCreate", async invite => {
  const log = client.channels.cache.get(`${`modlog_${message.guild.id}`}`)
  let inviteCreated = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  log.send(`An invite has been created on this server!`)
})
```

The issue is that since the `inviteCreate` event only accepts one parameter (I think that's what they are called) which is `invite`, there is no `message` parameter, so message becomes undefined, does anyone have a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Okay, it looks like your last edit is now a totally different question. You should upvote the ones helped you here if it was helpful (and both answers were as you managed to get the guild ID from the invite), and create a new question with the new details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `message` in this case. See the [documentation of `invite`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite).

- Your `message.member` can be replaced with [`invite.inviter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite?scrollTo=inviter)
- Your `message.channel` can be replaced with [`invite.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite?scrollTo=channel)
- Your `message.guild` can be replaced with [`invite.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite?scrollTo=guild)

Comment: Some nice extra info here, @NullDev ;)

Answer (score 2):

`Invite`s also have a [`guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite?scrollTo=guild) property, that's the guild the invite is for, so you can use that instead of the `message.guild`:

```js
client.on('inviteCreate', async (invite) => {
  const log = client.channels.cache.get(`${`modlog_${invite.guild.id}`}`);
  let inviteCreated = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
  log.send(`An invite has been created on this server!`);
});
```

Comment: I've checked it, and _"managed to find a solution"_ is not really helpful without knowing what that is

Comment: It should be a new question, not an edit. The original question is answered, @NullDev and I both answered how you can get the guild ID inside the `inviteCreate` event. Your last edit is not related to this.

Comment: oh ok sorry I will create a new question, thanks to both of you!

Comment: No worries, it's not a big issue :)